# Cannot open Powershell script with comma in filename via "context menu » edit"

Tags: windows-10, powershell, filenames, special-characters

I noticed that Windows 10 (at least the current stable build 1607) does not properly escape filenames when you try to open a PowerShell script (.ps1) via *context menu » Edit*.

While ampersand and spaces are treated correctly, Windows cannot open a file whose name has commas - the file name is truncated at the comma.

[image]

#### Resulting error

[image]

I am looking for some solution to this problem, whether via a registry fix or a way to add quotes, to escape the comma or anything else.

Comment: I get the same thing. Using `open with > notepad` seems to work, though. But yeah, Windows is definitely not handling commas correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change value in that registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Edit\Command` from `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe" "%1"` to `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe" """%1"""`. Or you can use following PowerShell command to do that:

```
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Edit\Command '(default)' '"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe" """%1"""'
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@user364455](https://superuser.com/users/364455/user364455)'s answer, this modifies both the >Edit and >Open context menu items, allowing you to open .ps1 files (with commas in the path) in ISE with elevation by either double-clicking on a .ps1 file or right-clicking in Explorer and choosing 'Edit'.  A here-string was used to save the headache of escaping quotes.  A PowerShell console window unfortunately pops up for a split second, which there are workarounds for (the most common one I've found involves VBScript).

PowerShell:

```
$newValue = @'
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Command "& {Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe -ArgumentList '""""""""%1""""""""' -Verb RunAs}"
'@

# Open
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command -Name '(default)' -Value $newValue -Force

# Edit
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\Edit\Command -Name '(default)' -Value $newValue -Force
```

.reg version

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Open
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@="PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Command \"& {Start-Process -FilePath C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell_ise.exe -ArgumentList '\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"%1\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"' -Verb RunAs}\""

; Edit
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\Edit\Command]
@="PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Command \"& {Start-Process -FilePath C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell_ise.exe -ArgumentList '\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"%1\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"' -Verb RunAs}\""
```